# Does not provide an export named 'Vue' (at main.js?t=1667997788986:1:9)

Tags: vue.js, express

I am developing an application in Express and Vue js
I'm getting this:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=460a75c2' does not provide an export named 'Vue' (at main.js?t=1667997788986:1:9)

App.vue file :

```
import {Vue, createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/main.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import vueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(axios, vueAxios)
createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

My main.js file is :

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                dataResponse: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async getDataResponse(){
                const res = await axios.get(`${this.baseUrl}/catalog/home`)
                    console.log(response)
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.getDataResponse()
        }
        
    }
</script>
<template>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 6):

You didn't write which version of Vue you are using, but based on the fact that you are using `createApp` it looks like you are using Vue 3.

In that case, the error is correct -- there is no export called Vue in the module `vue`. Vue 3 removed the default export, so you can't write `import Vue from 'vue'` anymore, and there is no export named `Vue` in the package, so `import { Vue } from 'vue'` is not valid either.

You're probably trying to follow an old tutorial about installing Vue plugins. In Vue 3, instead of writing `Vue.use(plugin)`, you would write `createApp().use(plugin)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If your are using Vue 2.7 and 3.x, do you mind if try `import { createApp } from 'vue'`, and then use `createApp(App).use(axios).use(vueAxios).mount('#app')`? It should be works because of import nature.

Another alternative:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/main.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import vueAxios from 'vue-axios'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(axios)
app.use(vueAxios)
app.mount('#app')
```